# Array is not getting printed in Java

Tags: java, arrays, output, system.out

I want to print an array of size n, where each element is pow(i,i),i ranging from 1 to n. i.e. if I input n = 4, it should return me an array A = {1, 4, 27, 256}. This is because power(1,1) = 1, power(2,2) = 4, power(3,3) = 27 and power(4,4) = 256.

But, when I try to run the below code, it is not giving any output.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Main s = new Main();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    double[] A = new double[n];
    int j ;
    for(j = 0; j <= n; j++)
    {
        A[j] = Math.pow(j+1, j+1);
        //System.out.println(A[j]); --> 1
    }
    System.out.print(A);
    System.out.println(A);  //-->2
    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(A[i]+" "); // --> 3
    }
}
}
```

When I try to remove commented quotes for equation 1, it is printing me the values. But neither of equation 2 or 3 is helping me to print the array.

Comment: you have an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. change for-loop to `for(j = 0; j < n; j++)`. To print the result you can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));`

Answer (score 2):

Try This :-

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main s = new Main();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        double[] A = new double[n];
        int j ;
        for(j = 0; j <= n-1; j++)
        {
            A[j] = Math.pow(j+1, j+1);
            //System.out.println(A[j]); --> 1
        }
        System.out.print(A);
        System.out.println(A);  //-->2
        for (int i=0; i<A.length-1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[i]+" "); // --> 3
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Main s = new Main();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    double[] A = new double[n];
    int j ;
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        A[j-1] = Math.pow(j, j);
        //System.out.println(A[j]); //--> 1
    }
    System.out.print(A);
    System.out.println(A);  //-->2
    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(A[i]+" "); // --> 3
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `j <= n;`, the loop condition should be `j < n` because the index start from 0 and ends at n - 1. If you try to access A[n], it will throw array index out of exception.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main s = new Main();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        double[] A = new double[n];
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            A[j] = Math.pow(j + 1, j + 1);
            //System.out.println(A[j]); --> 1
        }
        System.out.print(A);
        System.out.println(A);  //-->2
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(A[i] + " "); // --> 3
        }
    }
}
```